# saving login information on iPhone

Tags: applications, login-items

Is there a good app to store login information to various sites and services on my iPhone?

Answer (score 5):

I like [1Password](http://agilewebsolutions.com/onepassword).

Comment: I have 1Password on my Mac, my iPhone, and my iPad. Can't imagine life without it.

Answer (score 4):

I like [LastPass](http://lastpass.com/). More for it's Desktop/Browser Integration than the iOS specific version.

Comment: Plus lastpass is free and just bought xmarks. The year plan for premium is cheaper than 1pass pro for iphone and provide a free app. But I have to admit, 1pass website looks way better! :D

Comment: Lastpass is free if you only use it on one device. And yes, way cheaper in order to sync it across any/every device. 1Password does look better, but it works on par. I pay for pretty most of the time, but Lastpass just seems to work better for me. (I used 1Password before I used Lastpass.)

Answer (score 0):

PassDiary is great, no-nonsense and free.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Alistair Maxwell! Can you please add a link to the software you mention in your answer? It is always helpful to add a link to help the OP to find the right software. Thank you.